# How java script login page works?

Tags: javascript

How JavaScript take user ID and password? And where do it stores that data? And how it check the authentication when next time user wants to login in?

Comment: You've given very little information. Please can you provide more context, any code, etc, including a [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't. JavaScript running in the browser cannot perform meaningful authentication. You'd need a server-side application that performs the authentication. At most, JavaScript could perform an AJAX request, sending the user ID and password to the server — but how exactly you'd do that would depend entirely on the application. You'd need to read the documentation for your system to find out how authentication is performed.

(It is conceivable that we're talking about a server-side application written in JavaScript à la node.js, but since the question is not tagged as such I'm assuming not.)

Comment: Some one has said to me that you have to write API n then use basic HTTP request.

Comment: That's correct. JavaScript can perform an AJAX request to pass the data to your server via HTTP, but it still has to be your server-side application that's doing the work.